# Write VSCode extension to start debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp, vscode-extensions

I'll explain.

I have VSCode installed with Omnisharp's C# extension and I'm trying to debug a console application (which gets compiled as dll, using Microsoft.NETCore.App).

So, when I launch the application (F5) the debugger can't attach to it, I guess it's because in my **launch.json** file I have this:

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "dotnet.exe",
    "args": ["run"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "stopAtEntry": true
}
```

In this case, what I understand, is that dotnet.exe hosts the dll to be executed. So, in order to start debugging I have to run VSCode again in Attach mode, and give the process name in order to work:

```
{
    "name": ".NET Core Attach",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processName": "dotnet"
}
```

What I'm trying to acomplish here, is to write an extension which will execute and attach to the process using omnisharp's debug adapter. That would be the equivalent of the "launch" + ".NET Core Attach" (all in one call, without the need of stopping VSCode to hook into the target process).

So far, the extension (typescript) is doing this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.debug.start").then((s)=>{               
           vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Trying to attach...");
           //attach to dotnet.exe process
        },(err)=>{                
           vscode.window.showErrorMessage(err); 
        });
```

I'm missing the attach to the process part there :/ so, is there a way for the extension to, besides starting a process, also attach to it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know why Omnisharp does not work for you? Or you want to write an extension to replace it? Those two are completely different.